# Python module numpy not found even installed repeatedly

Tags: python, numpy

Under ubuntu18, when I use
`python3 somepy.py`
I got error: no module named numpy
Please refer to screen picture as below:
[image: numpy not found, but pip install show installed]

I searched a lot but didn't get out.

The command I'm using is "python3". I linked my `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/python3.8`

I also linked both `/usr/bin/pip` and `/usr/bin/pip3` to using the same pip3.8 path as shown in the picture.

Then I use `pip3 install numpy=1.20.1` and displayed already installed.

But "no module named numpy" still exists. I don't know why. Is there any help?

Thank for the quick replies. I'll add 3 more pictures:
This picture shows I had used `pip install -U numpy` and also shows how I run the python script
[image: pip install -U numpy and command line]

This picture: python3 -m pip install numpy. This works as Jortega suggested.
[image: python3 -m pip install numpy]

Comment: How are you running the python file/script? Also, try starting python in the command line (type `python3`, and then once it is running try `import numpy` and see if it is successful (`exit()` will exit python on the command line)

Comment: When in doubt, `python -m pip`

Comment: @fam-woodpecker Yes, In pure command line; I tried py shell, import is good. I'll add more picture.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to install `numpy`.

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: Hi, yes your suggestion makes some different errors. You may please have a look of my update. The install begin a new download. Even I prefer I can use an already-installed numpy module instead of a new install and the new installation still has issue I don't understand yet.

Comment: Latest trying is going on. May please wait I'm installing Cython as prompted

Comment: Your method works. I'll delete unusable pictures

Answer (score 1):

I installed numpy library with these commands

```
pip install -U numpy
pip3 install -U numpy
```

Comment: Yes, I run pip3 install -U numpy and succeeded before I post this question but no module error still exist. Sorry missed this information, I'll add the picture as trial history

Comment: have u tried to remove numpy and install again? i had some problem about numpy like this 3-4 weeks ago and i solved the problem by changing the version

Comment: Hi, I updated the post. I have did as you mentioned may please see the second picture and the rest.

Comment: I'm still trying please wait for my updates.

Comment: may the problem is in the pip?

Comment: Jortega's method fixed my problem. But I think your comment will help in this kind of issue. To my issue, I think it's caused by that the pip and python didn't work in pair. I'll use miniconda next time to avoid Python environment issues.